# bd relationship MySQL

Tags: mysql, relationship

I have the following relationship,

[image]

And wanted to know how I can get the team a game winner?

Comment: Pardon? I don't really understand the question. Could you clarify please?

Comment: I can't understand what you need either.

Comment: What is `bd`? Your question is impossible to answer, you are not giving enough information.

Comment: example

id_team = 12

select
   m.*,
  r.*
from matches m
inner join resuslt r
ON r.id_match = m.id_match
where 
m.id_home_team = 12 or m.id_away_team = 12 

This query I have all the games with the team's results 12. but I want to know the games won and lost

Comment: in a database that stores matches I have this relational structure to store matches and their games.

the next query I have all the games with the team's results 12.

example:

for id_team = 12

select m., r.

from matches m

inner join resuslt r

ON r.id_match = m.id_match

where

m.id_home_team = 12 or m.id_away_team = 12

This query I have all the games with the team's results 12.

how I can know the games won and lost a team? do you understand??

Comment: P.S. Your diagram has a possible spelling error: `matches.id_awat_team`... should be "away".

Comment: If it isn't possible for there to be multiple results per match, you could merge the matches/results tables.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
  m.id_match,
  IF((id_home_team = ? AND score_home_team > score_away_team) OR
    (id_away_team = ? AND score_home_team < score_away_team), 1, 0) AS won
FROM matches m
  JOIN results r ON(r.id_match = m.id_match)
WHERE 
  id_home_team = ? OR id_away_team = ?
```

Replace the `?` with your team's ID.

In [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6dc95/1).